# How exactly does a wand work and what affects its performance?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

I tried to find an answer to this, but nothing that I can find answers the question.

What I can't understand is that when Ron snaps his wand and tries to cast spells with it, they all backfire and seem to affect the caster.

What I can't seem to find an answer to is, what happens if you modify the wand, say making it shorter or sharpening the tip using some sandpaper. Say you snapped the very tip off, but sanded it down to look like it had not been broken.

- At what point does the wand not work as it should?
- Does a scratch that removes material from the wand affect
  performance?
- Will altering the shape slightly affect performance?
- Does the place it has been broken at affect how it performs?
- What governs and fully functional wand?

### Ultimately , how does a functional wand work and if it is physically modified does it affect the performance of it?

Answer (score 7):

**TLDR**: So it appears that both the wood casing, as well as the magical core both need to be fully intact to channel magic, while either being damaged can limit the magic, or stop the magic completely.

---

A wand is simply a conduit in which a witch or wizard uses to focus their magic.

> Oh yes, if you are any wizard at all you will be able to channel your magic through almost any instrument. -HP7

Imagine, a garden hose its attached to a fount of water at one end, the water travels through the hose, and can be pointed, directed, and sprayed out, at the users will.

Now what if the hose has kinks in it? holes? clogs? damage to the hose will limit the water that comes through, or in some cases cause the water to not come through at all.

Lets take our hose example and move it to wands. Wizards are a fount of magical power/energy, and they channel that energy through their wands towards their targets. As we see with a damaged hose a damaged wand works similarly, it can limit the magic that comes through, spray the magic in unintended directions, back up, or not work at all.

Lets get some examples going then shall we?

> He rummaged around in his trunk and pulled out a very battered-looking
>   wand. It was chipped in places and something white was glinting at the
>   end.
>
> ‘Unicorn hair’s nearly poking out. Anyway –’

Here we have Rons wand, from the outset the wands tip was chipped off and the unicorn hair core was exposed. This however, only seemed to have limited to no effect on performance as the unicorn hair itself was still intact. At least the performance was enough for a first year student to not have issues.

Hagrids wand was also able to function after being snapped in half, which leads me to believe that its core was not ripped in half either, though Hagrid had far more issues with his wand.

> “My wand,” said Ron, in a shaky voice. “Look at my wand —” It had
>   snapped, almost in two; the tip was dangling limply, held on by a few
>   splinters.

In year 2 Rons wand snapped nearly in half.

> He had patched up his
>   wand with some borrowed Spellotape, but it seemed to be damaged
>   beyond repair. It kept crackling and sparking at odd moments, and
>   every time Ron tried to transfigure his beetle it engulfed him in
>   thick gray smoke that smelled of rotten eggs.

His wand seems to be at the limit with only a small portion of it still "whole" able for some magic to enter, but the results were usually epic failures.

> Ron’s wand was still malfunctioning, surpassing itself
>   on Friday morning by shooting out of Ron’s hand in Charms and
>   hitting tiny old Professor Flitwick squarely between the eyes, creat-
>   ing a large, throbbing green boil where it had struck.
>
> A loud bang echoed around the stadium and a jet of green light
>   shot out of the wrong end of Ron’s wand, hitting him in the stom-
>   ach and sending him reeling backward onto the grass.

It even sent magic backwords towards the user twice.

Finally lets look at a wand damaged beyond repair(normal repair)

> The holly and phoenix wand was nearly severed in two. One
>   fragile strand of phoenix feather kept both pieces hanging
>   together. The wood had splintered apart completely. Harry took it
>   into his hands as though it was a living thing that had suffered a
>   terrible injury.

Here the wood is completely severed and the core is only attached by the tiniest piece, Harry's wand is now useless with practically no magic being able to traverse the conduit.

Like a garden hose, any damage to either the casing or blockage damage to the interior can cause undesired results, backups, magical leaks(loss of power), or complete and utter failure.

Comment: Nice one Himarm UV!

Comment: The hose analogy fails in that the hose isn't a conduit for something the human is channeling through it (the human just directs what is already flowing on it's own, and the human isn't required). A closer example might be a straw for a spitballer. Alone it's just a straw and does nothing on it's own, but through handling of a human (and based on their skill), spitballs can be shot out. A damaged straw can then lead to lesser/undesired effects, and shooting one with no straw is still possible, but not as easily or powerfully (like hand magic).